# Opening and passing arguments to an application using a shell script on a Mac

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script, arguments

I am trying to write a shell script on a Mac which opens RIATest and passes it parameters. My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo THIS TEST!!!

open -a '/Applications/RIATest 4/RIATest.app' --args /b  /r  /e 5  /p ..//FMNG_RIATest//doScriptGenerator.rtp  /rs ..//FMNG_RIATest//doScriptGenerator.rts  /rf ..//FMNG_RIATest/doScriptGenerator.rtw
```

As soon as I put an argument following --args the program does not open. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your formatting please. You indent code with `Ctrl-K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using dashes (`-`) for your arguments on OSX instead of forward slashes (`/`) .

It's not clearly mentioned in [their documentation](http://www.riatest.com/onlinedocs/v4/RIATest/CommandLine.html), but if you look at the top where they're explaining how to export RIATest to your path, you can see an example of the command-line switches being used. All of the other examples describe `RIATest.exe`, which is a windows executable, and explains why they have forward slashes. Just silently translate them into dashes when building your command line on OSX.

Comment: The `--args` thing should actually work, per `open`'s manpage.

Comment: I found the executable_name and tried this code                   open -a /Applications/'RIATest 4'/RIATest.app/Contents/MacOs/RIATest /b but I got an error which said that the file /b does not exist. When I added the --args before /b in that line it gave no error but the program still did not open. Thanks a lot for the quick responses!

Comment: @KevinDoherty Use `-` instead of `/` on the flags - `/` is for windows, `-` is for unix-like environments (MacOSX).

Comment: @KevinDoherty Updated my answer - see if your original attempt works with the dashes.

Comment: Good call with the dashes. But my original attempt still does not open the program. The only evidence I have that the script ran is the echo. For reference:                                   #!/bin/bash
echo THIS TEST!!!
open -a '/Applications/RIATest 4/RIATest.app' --args -b  -r  -e 5   -p ..//FMNG_RIATest//doScriptGenerator.rtp  -rs ..//FMNG_RIATest//doScriptGenerator.rts  -rf ..//FMNG_RIATest/doScriptGenerator.rtw                            Once again, thanks a lot for your time